# SecurityException opening provider com.urbanairship.UrbanAirship Provider from ProcessRecord that is not exported from uid

Tags: android, urbanairship.com

I not getting what this AndroidRuntime Error actually.

When my project crash because i didn't close my database from which I's reading values.

Actually this happens when my database accessing activity is open and I gain run project on that device(Xoom) from my editor.

Log for crash is given below.

```
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/SQLiteDatabase(5384): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.android.mypype/databases/ua_analytics.db' 
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/SQLiteDatabase(5384): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/SQLiteDatabase(5384):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1980)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/SQLiteDatabase(5384):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:977)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/SQLiteDatabase(5384):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:956)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/SQLiteDatabase(5384):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1021)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/SQLiteDatabase(5384):     at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:734)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/SQLiteDatabase(5384):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/SQLiteDatabase(5384):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:149)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/SQLiteDatabase(5384):     at com.urbanairship.analytics.EventDataManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/SQLiteDatabase(5384):     at com.urbanairship.analytics.Analytics.<init>(Unknown Source)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/SQLiteDatabase(5384):     at com.urbanairship.UAirship.takeOff(Unknown Source)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/SQLiteDatabase(5384):     at com.android.mypype.MypypeApplication.onCreate(MypypeApplication.java:93)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/SQLiteDatabase(5384):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:968)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/SQLiteDatabase(5384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3598)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/SQLiteDatabase(5384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:122)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/SQLiteDatabase(5384):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1040)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/SQLiteDatabase(5384):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/SQLiteDatabase(5384):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/SQLiteDatabase(5384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/SQLiteDatabase(5384):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/SQLiteDatabase(5384):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/SQLiteDatabase(5384):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/SQLiteDatabase(5384):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/SQLiteDatabase(5384):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.android.mypype.MypypeApplication: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.urbanairship.UrbanAirshipProvider from ProcessRecord{40ee74e8 5384:com.android.mypype:mypype_location_service/10069} (pid=5384, uid=10069) that is not exported from uid 10122
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3601)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:122)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1040)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.urbanairship.UrbanAirshipProvider from ProcessRecord{40ee74e8 5384:com.android.mypype:mypype_location_service/10069} (pid=5384, uid=10069) that is not exported from uid 10122
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1321)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1275)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.getContentProvider(ActivityManagerNative.java:2014)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.getProvider(ActivityThread.java:3673)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.acquireProvider(ActivityThread.java:3698)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContextImpl.java:1565)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContentResolver.java:909)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:296)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at com.urbanairship.UrbanAirshipResolver.query(Unknown Source)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at com.urbanairship.PreferencesResolver.get(Unknown Source)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at com.urbanairship.Preferences.getPreferenceFromDatabase(Unknown Source)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at com.urbanairship.Preferences.getPreference(Unknown Source)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at com.urbanairship.Preferences.getInt(Unknown Source)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at com.urbanairship.analytics.AnalyticsPreferences.getMaxBatchSize(Unknown Source)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at com.urbanairship.analytics.EventUploadManager.loadPrefs(Unknown Source)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at com.urbanairship.analytics.EventUploadManager.<init>(Unknown Source)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at com.urbanairship.analytics.Analytics.<init>(Unknown Source)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at com.urbanairship.UAirship.takeOff(Unknown Source)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at com.android.mypype.MypypeApplication.onCreate(MypypeApplication.java:93)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:968)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3598)
11-01 12:09:27.090: E/AndroidRuntime(5384):     ... 10 more
```

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: I came across the dame problem on Samsung Note with android version 4.0.4. Any help will be appropriated. [Question link here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859840/application-crashes-on-installation-with-error-sqlite3-exec-failed-to-set-sync/13859865)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This thing works for me..

```
AirshipConfigOptions options = AirshipConfigOptions
                .loadDefaultOptions(this);

        UAirship.takeOff(this, options);

        PushManager.enablePush();
```

Hope it works for you too.

Comment: @Vaiden  you can also check this link for solution were i handled exception.[Link...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859840/application-crashes-on-installation-with-error-sqlite3-exec-failed-to-set-sync)

Answer (score 0):

Check your manifest, you should rename many things with your package name.
Search for "your" in manifest and modify them.

Comment: Why is this happening i'm accessing my device database actually not in any relationship with urbanairship?

Comment: some suggest it's because of proguard, i'll check it and let you know!

Comment: yes, in my case change order of libraries in project properties

Comment: can you please provide any link or elaborate what exactly needs to do.

Comment: I figure it out It's just because i wasn't close database reference.

Comment: thanks for your help  Can you help me out in this question [Quesiotn Link...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13859840/application-crashes-on-installation-with-error-sqlite3-exec-failed-to-set-sync)

Comment: So the answer marked as correct is wrong.
AandroidNewbie - please provide the correct solution.